# Multi-site WCF Service

Tags: wcf, networking, firewall, nat

I have implemented a WCF service that will be used at Site A with 5 computers in the LAN accessing the service.

What I would like to do is have an elevated user/administrator be able to use one of the 5 machines and query an identical service at Site B (also with 5 computers) that they will need to connect to by bypassing the LAN firewall.Accessing data from Site A to Site B (and vica-versa) need only be read-only

Is there a standardised way to acheive this using WCF?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said, there are two sites, each with 5 PCs, and one server.  In each case the server runs a WCF service, that some application on the 5 PCs will access.

You said you have a WCF service.  You didn't say how you were accessing it - in other words what the client app is.

- Supposing that you use WCF client libraries, 
  You can [specify the binding address in configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx) (app.exe.config), or in application code.
- if you connect via a browser and AJAX, it's just a different URL that you specify.
- if you use something else, then... ?

Also I don't understand what you mean by "bypass the firewall".  This doesn't bypass any firewalls and I don't think you want to.  It might *traverse* a firewall, but not bypass it.

And, this leaves it up to YOU to figure out how to enable or disable access to the of-site service, whether that is an administrative/privileged user thing, or just a user-selectable address.  An example of the latter would be to allow the user to select "Site A" or "Site B" in a dropdown box, within a WPF UI.

Comment: I have suggested what you have said, but what they want is a single address/binding/contract on each users machine. When a user connects to the server that is an administrator, they then want logic to send the request to Site B from the server, and not on the client.

I am in a position where I cannot disagree, as my suggestion was to have the logic on the client so that when they request data from site B you just change the endpoint, "they" want this to happen on the server.

Part of the issue is a lack of understanding of service orientation, but you work with what you have.